# How to build a table/tibble/df for parallel execution time for multiple sources?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, execution

Suppose I have a set of scripts with the following inside:
Each script print into console 'hello world' and script execution time.

```
t0<- Sys.time()

print('hello world')

t1<- Sys.time()
time.taken<- round(as.numeric(t1-t0), 2)
time.taken
cat(paste("\n[script1] -","Execution time: ", time.taken, "seconds"))
```

Now I am trying to get the time execution for multiple sources:

```
source("modules/script1.R")
source("modules/script2.R")
source("modules/script3.R")
source("modules/script4.R")
source("modules/script5.R")
source("modules/script6.R")
```

However this will print the execution time separately for each script and in the console not in the environment,
Would be great to get something like this inside R environment:

```
#script  execution time
#1             2 seconds
#2             2 seconds
#3             2 seconds
#4             2 seconds
#5             2 seconds
#6             2 seconds
```

Is this even possible?
What resources are available for this kind of processing?

Comment: Instead of multiple source files, it may be better to build a package

Comment: Hey @akrun, do you know any resources (links/repos)  to start with this?

Comment: If you meant about creating packages, perhaps [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio) can help.  Generally, I create packages instead of multiple source files, because this can trigger some bugs esp when you are sourcing in RMD files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `parLapply` on Windows or `mclapply` from `parallel` package to run the scripts in parallel.

The last value calculated in the script is passed to the `source` function.

If you make sure the last value of the script is its execution time, it will be returned as a `list` by `lapply`:

```
library(parallel)

l <- 1:6
# Create script files
createscript <- function(numscript) {
  cat('
    t0<- Sys.time()
    print("hello world")
    Sys.sleep(runif(1))
    t1<- Sys.time()
    time.taken<- round(as.numeric(t1-t0), 2)
    time.taken
    print(paste("[script1] -","Execution time: ", time.taken, "seconds")) 
    data.frame(time.taken)'
    ,file =paste0("Script",numscript,".R") , append = F)
  T
}


lapply(l,createscript)

# Scripts list
scripts <- paste0("Script",l,".R")

# Run scripts in parallel
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", detectCores() - 1))
result <- parLapply(cl, scripts,function(script) {source(script)$value})
do.call(rbind,result)

  time.taken
1       0.87
2       0.51
3       0.61
4       0.38
5       0.37
6       0.91
```